# go to python cell in script from vs code interractive window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-console

I am using vs code to run my python codes. I use the interractive window, and sometimes I get a bit lost when trying to find where in my script a cell displaying in the interractive window was run. Is there a way to go to cell script from the interractive window (illustration below)?
[image: illustration of my goal]

I tried to check [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_additional-commands-and-keyboard-shortcuts) keyboard shortkeys for interractive window, and I don't see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `#%%` to execute a line or a segment of code in the Python script, `Go To [*]` will be displayed after the `Run` command. Click it will jump to the corresponding cell.

[image]

The reverse operation is the intermediate icon of suspended display in the upper right corner of the unit grid in the interactive window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the code in the interactive window you see a few buttons.

Press the one with the **little arrow in the top-left corner**, next to the trash bin